# Avoid object destruction when initializing in local scope, C++

Tags: c++, initialization, destructor

I am working on a networking project and I need to initialize an object in a try-catch block. I want the object, which represents a socket, to close the socket upon destruction, but I must avoid closing a socket before using it. A socket is represented with something as simple as an integer value which is why closing it is very easy, or rather hard to avoid.

In essence, I have the following (simplified) code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    int v;

    Foo() {
        cerr << "Foo default constructor with v = " << v << ".\n";
    }

    Foo(int newV) : v(newV) {
        cerr << "Foo constructor with v = " << v << ".\n";
    }

    ~Foo() {
        cerr << "Foo destructor with v = " << v << ".\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    try {
        foo = Foo(3);
    } catch (...) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

which yields the following output:

```
Foo default constructor with v = 0.
Foo constructor with v = 3.
Foo destructor with v = 3.
Foo destructor with v = 3.
```

This is a problem for me, because Foo has been destroyed twice with the value `3`. Once, at the end of the program, and once after exiting the `try` block after an assignment operation.

My question is: can I instantiate an object by destroying its default value and constructing it in-place, instead of constructing another object and performing an assignment?

Of course, there are workarounds like using `new`, but I do not want to be forced to dereference an object everywhere and also I want to make sure it gets destroyed in case of an error (although of course for that I could use some pointer wrapper). I also do not want to use some separate C-style initialization method because I consider that ugly. I also have other members inside my "Foo" class, so I would need to perform some sort of destruction during assignment, which is inconvenient. Ideally, I'd love to see something akin to

```cpp
Foo foo;
try {
    Foo foo(3);
} catch (...) {
    // handle exception
}
```

but I cannot do that because that leads to a redeclaration, or rather a shadow-declaration and on top of that, the more-local Foo object will be destroyed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of this just when I was finishing typing up the question. Use move-assignment.

Take the original code and add the following method to the class definition:

```cpp
Foo & operator=(Foo && other) {
    swap(v, other.v);
    return *this;
}
```

This way, when constructing an object only to assign it to some other object, this method will be called and it will simply swap the values in the `v` members. The `other` object will be immediately destroyed, but with the "old" value of `v`.

Take care to assign some meaningless value to `v` by default, perhaps `-1`.

Now, the output of the program is

```
Foo default constructor with v = 0.
Foo constructor with v = 3.
Foo destructor with v = 0.
Foo destructor with v = 3.
```

which is exactly what I was looking for.